# How can I batch rename files on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, batch-rename

I have many files like these:

```
simple-1.gif
simple-2.gif
simple-3.gif
```

I want to use command prompt to rename them all with the same pattern so they look:

```
aa1.gif
aa2.gif
aa3.gif
```

I tried with this:

```
ren simple-*.* aa*.*
```

but this is what I get

aample-1.gif

which is not what I intended. What's the trick here?

Comment: The trick is to use Batch Rename Utility instead of a `.bat`. https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Comment: cant be done just from the cmd??

Comment: It sure can, but this is the method I would prefer.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can tell me how to do it on cmd please.

Comment: Someone will come along and write a beautiful batch answer here soon (probably). You already got a .exe and a powershell answer, batch is probably next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be a batch example:

```
@echo off

Title Rename Files Keeping the Numbers

for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

:InfoPasta
cls
echo.
if exist "%~1" (if exist "%~1\" set "Pasta=%~1") else (set /p "Pasta=%BS% Please Inform the Folder: ")
If not exist "%Pasta%\" goto :PastaInexistente

set /p "Prefixo=%BS% Please set a prefix: "

set Digitos=0
set Contador=2
if exist "%~dp0temp.txt" del /q "%~dp0temp.txt"

pushd "%Pasta%"
:: NArquivos = Numero de Arquivos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.*') do set /a NArquivos+=1
if %NArquivos% EQU 0 Exit
 
echo - %Date% - %time:~0,5%:>>"%~dp0rename.log"
echo.>>"%~dp0rename.log"

call :Digitos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.*') do for /f "delims=0123456789" %%b in ("%%~a") do call :Numeros "%%~a" "%%~nb"


for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=;" %%a in ('type "%~dp0temp.txt"^|sort') do IF not exist "%%b" (
                                                                                           ren "%%a" "%%b"
                                                                                           echo "%%a" -^> "%%b">>"%~dp0rename.log"
echo "%%a" -^> "%%b"
                                                                                          ) else (call :Renomear "%%~a" "%%~b")
echo.>>"%~dp0rename.log"
if exist "%~dp0temp.txt" del /q "%~dp0temp.txt"
exit

:Digitos
call set Var=%%NArquivos:~%Digitos%,1%%
If not Defined Var goto :EOF
set /a Digitos+=1
goto :Digitos

:: NC = Nome Completo
:: NP = Nome Parcial
:: AP = Apenas Numeros

:Numeros
if "%~1"=="%~2" goto :EOF
set "NC=%~n1"
set "NP=%~n2"
call set "AP=%%NC:%NP%=%%"
set APZ=00000%AP%
call set "APZ=%%APZ:~-%Digitos%%%"
>>"%~dp0temp.txt" echo %Prefixo%%APZ%%~x1;%~1;%Prefixo%%AP%%~x1
goto :EOF

:PastaInexistente
echo.
echo  This Folder doesn't exist! "%Pasta%"
pause 2>nul | echo  Press a key | set /p=
goto :InfoPasta

:Renomear
IF not exist "%~n2 [%Contador%]%~x2" (
                                      ren "%~1" "%~n2 [%Contador%]%~x2"
                                      echo "%~1" -^> "%~n2 [%Contador%]%~x2">>"%~dp0rename.log"
echo "%~1" -^> "%~n2 [%Contador%]%~x2"
                                      goto :EOF
                                     )
set /a Contador+=1
goto :Renomear
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, thats a great tool right there.

Comment: Hi, again, sorry how can I skip the set order prompt since I will always sort by name and never by date?

Comment: Just remove the line where it asks for the order and remove the %Ordem% variable form:  dir /b /a-d /s %Ordem% since ordering by name is the default.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: sorry again, but I tested it now and it doesnt seem to work. It still sorts by date.

Comment: okay I think I know whats the problem here. My files are something like simple-1, simple-2 and so on up to simple-50 and so when the batch file does its thing it sorts the files like this simple-1, simple11, simple12 and so on and renames them to aa1, aa2 and aa3 thus changing the original order. The solution is to use 2 digits in the file numbers unless there is another workaround I dont know of.

Comment: That's how the batch file was originaly it put some zeros to the left if you had up to 99 photos it would name01.jpg name02.jpg name03.jpg if you had up 999 photos it would rename to name001.jpg name002.jpg name003. But since you wanted to rename to aa1.gif aa2.gif aa3.gif I assumed you didn't want zeros to the left....

Comment: Please check the updated answer which put zeros to the left...

Comment: yes, you had assumed correctly. I dont want zeros to the left because my files look like this as of now: simple-1, simple-2, simple-3 etc. so I want them renamed to aa1, aa2, aa3 and so on which your original batch did. However I noticed that if the original name has no zeros to the left then the sorting is not done in the right order, thats why I tried by adding a zero like simple-01 to have it renamed to aa1. That does the trick but now I have to rename all the one-digit-name files before running the batch.

Comment: Also, I noticed another issue. Some of my files skip numbers in purpose like: simple-1, simple-2, simple-3 and then skips to simple-7 (so no 4,5,6) but after running the bat file they become aa1, aa2, aa3 and aa4 which should be aa7. Is there anyway to keep the original number intact? Thank you.

Comment: I think i almost got the trick to make it work that way....

Comment: thanks, Im trying myself but I have little to no experience in batch files.

Comment: I think I got it now see the updated answer.

Comment: yes! you got it! Beautiful bat! Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

With Powershell, use the following cmdlets:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Filter 'simple-*gif' | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName -Replace 'simple-', 'aa'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option. Below is a Batch File adapted from code I have previously written on Win10. You just need to enter the four variables at the start.
It will search for all filenames matching the pattern specified in string3, then replace all occurrences of string1 with string2 in those filenames.

As a bonus it will perform a safety check to ensure that the proposed new filename doesn't start or end with a space or a dot, and will trim them off before the rename. (This can happen if, for example, you use this code to convert underscores or dashes to spaces and the original filename began with one).

This does not rename extensions.

Note again, this will replace ALL instances of string1 with string2, so do not use if you wouldn't want, for e.g. "simple-1simple-2" to be renamed as "aa1aa2".

do not use "s in setting any of the variables aside from the ones already there.

By default it only echoes the rename commands but without actually performing them. Delete the echo before the ren command once you've satisfied yourself that it does what you want.

If you really only want filenames starting with string1 to be renamed, remember to delete the first asterisk in the pattern specified in string3.
e.g.

```
set "str1=simple-"
set "str2=aa"
set "str3=simple-*.gif"
```

The Batch File:

```
@echo off
set "dir=source directory path"
set "str1=original string"
set "str2=replacement string"
set "str3=*%str1%*.*"

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`dir "%dir%\%str3%" /a:-d /b /s /-p`) DO (call:rename_sub "%%F")

set /p pause=paused
exit

:rename_sub
set "file=%~n1"
if not defined file exit /b
call set "file=%%file:%str1%=%str2%%%"

:rename_valid_check
if "%file%"=="%~n1" exit /b
if not defined file exit /b
if "%file:~0,1%"==" " (set "file=%file:~1%"
    goto rename_valid_check)
if "%file:~-1%"==" " (set "file=%file:~0,-1%"
    goto rename_valid_check)
if "%file:~0,1%"=="." (set "file=%file:~1%"
    goto rename_valid_check)
if "%file:~-1%"=="." (set "file=%file:~0,-1%"
    goto rename_valid_check)

echo ren %1 "%file%%~x1"
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you but I couldnt make your code run. It says the file couldnt be found.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. All I can say is that it works for me on Win10 20H2, but I see you have asked for Win7, so maybe it doesn't work for that OS? If so hopefully some of the other solutions will.

Comment: @Cain Nuke Just a thought, but did you leave all the original quotes in place when setting the source directory and other initial variables? As in, one before the variable name, and one after the entered path or string text (and with no quotes used in the string or path text itself? Or maybe you could try removing all the quotes from each of the initial four variables, and set the values without using any quotes at all? Just a thought if you haven't already settled on another solution

Comment: No problem, I appreciate it anyway. Thank you.